# align c++ class attributes to the last word preceding semicolon ; in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, text-align, spacemacs

How would I align attributes in class definition with emacs align-regepx function?
An example string

```
Vector<double> total_productivity;        
std::vector< std::vector<double> > productivities;
```

should be converted into

```
Vector<double>                     total_productivity;        
std::vector< std::vector<double> > productivities;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.
to match this particular substring I used the following regular expression:

```
[a-z_]+;
```

It would take a more complex expression in the brackets but the idea is clear.